# How to search multiple columns in mysql using FULLTEXT Search?

Tags: mysql, database, jakarta-ee

Anyone can tell me how to search from multiple columns, Like When i will search "Htc one" Then all of Htc One Mobiles will display

```
SELECT brand_name,model_name from mobiles where MATCH(brand_name,model_name)Against("Htc One")
```

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysql [Like Operator](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) for this task. See example

```
SELECT * FROM `your_table` WHERE `your_column` LIKE '%something%'
```

Comment: Thank You for your answer ,But. i know your answer. Actually when i will search **HTC ONE M8** this will display at the first position of record and all similar **HTC ONE**  product should be diplay with "HTC ONE M9" so that's why i think FULL TEXT Search will be helpful

Comment: @KevalBhatt What do you means `FULL TEXT` ? Can you explain please

Comment: Check out this link :-  http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mysql-full-text-search-functions.php